# canvas background turns black after rerender fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I have the following situation: I draw the canvas with a background image and this works:

```
var canvasSection = new fabric.Canvas('buildSection', {
  selectionColor: 'rgba(94,213,94,0.2)',
  width: widthS,
  height: heightS,
  hoverCursor: 'pointer',
  backgroundColor: ({
    source: 'image/bordenconfigurator/background/background1.png',
    repeat: 'repeat'
  })

});
```

But then I need to clear canvas and to redraw it. at this point when I try to set background, instead of an image I see a black screen. In console I can see that the background image is set however. This is the code I'm trying:

```
$('#cForm').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).val() == 'rectLandsc') {
    widthS = 600;
    heightS = 400;

  } else if ($(this).val() == 'rectPortr') {
    ....

  }
  canvasSection.clear();

  canvasSection.set({
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    //  backgroundColor: ({source: 'image/bordenconfigurator/background/background1.png', repeat: 'repeat'})
  });
  //canvasSection.backgroundColor({source: 'image/bordenconfigurator/background/background.png', repeat:'repeat'});
  canvasSection.setBackgroundColor({
      source: 'image/bordenconfigurator/background/background.png'
    }),
    canvasSection.renderAll.bind(canvas);
  drawBaseForm();
  canvasSection.renderAll();

  console.log(canvasSection);
});
```

Is it a kind of a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Its because you are filling canvas with `fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
canvas.setBackgroundColor({
  source: 'image/bordenconfigurator/background/background1.png',
  repeat: 'repeat'
}, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

[setBackgroundColor](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setBackgroundColor) first parameter is color/pattern and second parameter is callback function.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setBackgroundColor({
  source: 'http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg'
}, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

function clearCanvas(){
 var background = canvas.backgroundColor;
 canvas.clear();
 setTimeout(function(){
  canvas.setBackgroundColor(background,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 },2000)
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border: 2px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='clearCanvas()'>clear</button>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work. No background is set, it is white. (I check also in console). In the code I tried above the backgroundimage is set, but the screen background is black instead of image after clearing the canvas and setting the background again.

Comment: Make a snippet, I will try to help

Comment: @AleksandraChuprova check the demo

Comment: @AleksandraChuprova Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/hfxfsnxz/6/). Image is drawing properly, the reason is getting it black because the rect you are creating filling with black and it comes on top of the image.

Comment: thanks a lot! it is working fine now. I was not aware that you can leave the fill property empty for transparent background.